# Как сделать так, чтобы поле облегало текст?

Tags: javascript, html, input

```
<input type=text class="input">
```

Как сделать текстовое поле облегающим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант с помощью JS:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let txt = "Привет!";
input.setAttribute("value", txt);
input.style.width = txt.length+ 'em';
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="input">
</div>
```

Восемь пикселей--это примерная длина символа.

Comment: Не надежнее ли привязаться к `em` вместо `px`?

Comment: Это ответ к вопросу. Насчёт em не знаю